# Thread priority and critical section

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I have two threads created using the `CreateThread()` function of the Windows API. My first thread (let's call it IMPORTANT_FAST_ACCESS) pushes some data onto a stack. The second thread (let's call it STACK_ACCESS_SLOW) want's to pop some data off that stack and work with it.

The problem is I want the IMPORTANT_FAST_ACCESS thread to be able to access the stack **immediately** without waiting for the second thread to do it's operation on it. So I basically want the IMPORTANT_FAST_ACCESS to be allowed to access the stack whenever it wants while the STACK_ACCESS_SLOW thread will look for when it is not used by the other thread and grab pop the stack data it wants.

However what if STACK_ACCESS_SLOW starts to access the stack because it was free 1 second ego but now IMPORTANT_FAST_ACCESS decided it wants to push some data on it and cannot wait?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You requirements imply that Thread2 can never block Thread1 from using the shared stack. Which means that T2 can never access the stack for fear of blocking T1. So to make this work you are going to have to accept some contention between the threads. It sounds like a classic case of just wrapping the stack in a critical section.

Comment: I don't quite understand exactly what you want here. It seems like you want the ability for your critical threaded code to have transactions.  Software Transactional Memory is still kind of nebulous and experimental. 

Why wouldn't a lock free stack or queue work?

Comment: You might want to reconsider whether a stack is the most appropriate mechanism.

Comment: Basically to clarify things a bit more: one thread prepares structs and fiils them with data to be send over tcp, while the other thread will look for which ones are full and ready to be transmitted. If thread1 is slowed by an x amount of time then it might lose some important data which it should use to fill the structs, and that is why I want to avoid locking the stack on which the structs are pushed on. Maybe there is a lock-free approach to this?

Comment: A stack really does seem inappropriate for this use case.  Can you clarify why you're using a stack?

Comment: You're in luck. Windows provides a [lock-free stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684121(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Actually, in view of Raymond's comments, can you clarify what you *mean* by a stack?  If you're just pushing and popping pointers, then the lock-free stack should do nicely - though even a lock-based stack would probably be OK, since you'd only have to lock it briefly; unless you're worried about priority inversion?

Comment: 'it might lose some important data which it should use to fill the structs' - hmm... this smells like an XY problem.  It sounds like there is an issue upstream of this stack-thingy that ought to be fixed first.  As others have hinted at, if the upstream thread cannot be delayed by the time required to push a pointer onto a CS-protected stack/queue, then there is a big problem with the requirement or implementation.

Comment: Okay maybe a stack is not the most appropriate thing but I've told you exactly what the two threads are doing. The Thread1 captures some data from somewhere at a really fast interval stores them in structs of size lets say 500 bytes, and there may be 2-3 of these structs produced every second. Now the second thread has to look somehow for this newly created structs which it has not sent yet, send them over tcp and delete them. But thread1 cannot afford to lose valuable time by waiting for Thread2 to unlock the space where it will be storing the structs.

Comment: Maybe a stack is not right but it seemed at first a convinient idea

Comment: @Panayiotis In thread2 you seem to be proposing to lock the stack, send an item, delete the item and unlock the stack.  Which will certainly block thread1.  Why not lock the stack, delete the item from the stack, unlock the stack, send the item and delete the item?  Also, you might want a queue rather than a stack.

Answer (score 2):

You have to synchronize access to the shared stack, no matter how fast or slow the threads are.  You cannot allow one thread to modify the stack while another thread is using it, and vice versa.

If you don't want the faster thread to be delayed by the slower thread, you have to make sure the slower thread does not keep a lock on the stack while processing it.  That means having the slower thread either:

1. pop stack items one at a time, locking and unlocking the stack each time.
2. lock the stack, make a copy/swap of it, unlock it, and process the copy as needed.